# BasicAuthentication does not authenticate user when checking permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I want to use DRF's `rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication` to develop my SPA with a dev server while consuming data from a locally running backend.

I included `rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication`  in `settings.py`. I have a view which requires Permission (`guardian.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin`):

```
class WidgetDetail(PermissionRequiredMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    permission_required = "widget.view_widget"
    return_403 = True
```

If I try to `GET` the widget using basic auth, the view returns an error 403. Using the debugger, I can see that when `PermissionRequiredMixin.check_permissions()` is run, `request.user` is AnonymousUser rather than the user provided by basic auth as [DRF's documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication) indicates.

Why is the user provided by basic auth not identified when permissions are checked?

Comment: It means `BasicAuthentication` didn't find the user. Are you sending the correct credentials?

Comment: Yes, I am certain about that. What puzzles me is that if I set a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L64) I can see that the function is never called when requesting `WidgetDetail` view. I guess I get something fundamentally wrong about authentication, but I just don't know what.

Comment: Hmm can you share your rest framework settings and a sample request with the basic auth header?

Comment: Sure, although there isn't much to share. My rest framework settings are simply `REST_FRAMEWORK = {"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication")}` and the sample request contains the `'Authorization': 'Basic ZmY6MTIz',` which corresponds to the user 'ff' with password '123'.